# Disable systemd inhibitors

Tags: 16.04, systemd

Ever since I changed to Xubuntu 16.04 there is an annoying behavior when suspending my laptop: it seems like there's a delay so that the network manager can turn off. This causes long suspend and resume time. The new times are 10-15 seconds which are way longer than what I had before...

Anyway, it seems like systemd-inhibit may be responsible for this. The command systemd-inhibit lists the delay before sleep since NetworkManager needs to turn off networks. There's also another inhibitor which blocks completely xfce4 power management.

How can I get rid of the systemd inhibitors? It is possible to disable them somehow?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and the following fixed it for me:

edit the file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

There is a list of entries that define, among other things, delay times for `systemd` (and `systemd-inhibit`!)

I uncommented (removed the leading `#`) from this line:

```
InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
```

and saved the file. That immediately remedied the delay. When I close the laptop lid, the system goes to suspend immediately.

[Reference - freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html)

Comment: This did not work for me. However I found a solution while trying to solve another problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

First find run `locate org.freedesktop.login1.policy` to find where the file is located then open it in a text editor, for example.

Find the block corresponding to `<action id="org.freedesktop.login1.inhibit-block-idle">` and make sure you have

```
<defaults>
   <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
   <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
   <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

The problem was that before only root users could bypass the inhibitors. Now the system suspends like before in just a few seconds.

Comment: In my case, there are 5 files. Should I modify all of them?